# What is the meaning of "/" in linux shell between 2 linux commands?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

I tried this command in shell. But I am unable to understand the output. Can someone explain?

```
du -h directory / ls directory
```

the output that i got was:

```
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/16x16
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/192x192
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/22x22
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/24x24
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/256x256
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/32x32
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/36x36
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/48x48
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/512x512
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/64x64
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/72x72
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/96x96
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/actions
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/animations
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/categories
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/devices
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/emblems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/emotes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/filesystems
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/intl
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/mimetypes
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/places
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/chart
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/code
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/data
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/form
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/image
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/io
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/media
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/navigation
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/net
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/object
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/table
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock/text
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/stock
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/scalable
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/apps
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic
55K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/hicolor
1.5M    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/redglass/cursors
1.5M    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/redglass
13K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/actions/16
5.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/actions/22
5.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/actions/24
24K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/actions
72K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/animations/22
72K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/animations/24
143K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/animations
12K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/16
39K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/22
34K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/24
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/48
84K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps
2.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/categories/22
7.0K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/categories/24
9.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/categories
6.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/mimes/16
7.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/mimes/22
7.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/mimes/24
22K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/mimes
5.0K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/places/16
6.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/places/22
6.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/places/24
6.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/places/32
6.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/places/48
6.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/places/64
38K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/places
483K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/16
572K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22
301K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/24
1.4M    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/128
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/16
2.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/22
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/24
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/32
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/48
512     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/64
3.0K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock
1.7M    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
13K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/actions/16
5.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/actions/22
5.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/actions/24
24K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/actions
72K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/animations/22
72K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/animations/24
143K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/animations
12K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/16
39K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/22
34K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/24
0       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/48
84K     /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps
2.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/categories/22
7.0K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/categories/24
9.5K    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/categories
```

the output is not complete...there were more similar locations.

Can someone please explain the output?

Comment: unless you have a file named `ls` in current directory, you should get a `file not found` error.

Comment: I expect that you wanted to use `;` in the command line instead of `/`. You'll then get the disk space used by the directory and all of its subdirectories followed by a listing of contents of the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You ran this commnad:

```
du -h [path1] [path2] [path3] [...] [pathN]
```

you got it, right? those are ***path*** and that `/` is your root directory beside other three which one of them `directory` is duplicated.

Comment: i.e. your `/` got taken as `path2`, and `ls` and `directory` are taken as `path3` and `path4` respectively, and somewhere at middle of the output you should see that path/directory `ls` does not exist. Unless you have directory named `ls` in your current directory of course.